# How to replace with NA all values that are longer than 4 digits in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame z

```
Name Date
a    1940
b    Before 1967
c    1867-68
d    c. 1950
```

I need to clean my data and leave only the exact dates.
My idea is to replace with NA all values that are longer than 4 digits, so the result will be

```
Name Date
a    1940
b    NA
c    NA
d    NA
```

How can I do that?
Are there any other ways to clean this data and get only the exact dates?

Comment: `as.numeric(z$Date)` would give the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Date` field is of character type, you can use the function `nchar` to get the number of characters

```
i = which(nchar(df$Date) > 4) # indices of rows with Date length > 4
df$Date[i] = NA
```

Output:

```
  Name Date
1    a 1940
2    b <NA>
3    c <NA>
4    d <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also works:

```
z$Date[which(nchar(z$Date)!=4)]<-NA

  Name Date
1    a 1940
2    b <NA>
3    c <NA>
4    d <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative using the `replace` function.

```
library(tidyverse)
z %>% mutate(Date = replace(Date, str_length(df$Date)>4, NA))
   

#    Name Date
#1    a 1940
#2    b <NA>
#3    c <NA>
#4    d <NA>
```

**Data**

```
z <- data.frame(Name = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), Date = c("1940", "Before 1967", "1867-68", "c.1950"))
```

Comment: or `df %>% mutate_at("Date", ~replace(.,str_length(.)>4, NA))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
z %>%
    mutate(Date = str_extract(Date,"^\\d{4}$"))
#  Name Date
#1    a 1940
#2    b <NA>
#3    c <NA>
#4    d <NA>
```

#### data

```
z <- structure(list(Name = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), Date = c("1940", 
"Before 1967", "1867-68", "c.1950")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```